# GUI for monitoring CPU usage (including L1/L2 caches) in real time?

Tags: performance, cpu, monitoring

Is there any GUI available in Ubuntu which shows detailed CPU usage, including L1/L2 cache usage? So that while running a custom program, I can monitor the CPU utilization in detail.

The default system monitor only shows the overall cpu utilization, but I'd like to also monitor the cache utilization / usage, and see how my code can affect it.

Comment: To my knowledge (and I would be happy to be proven incorrect), on modern systems (especially Intel), the cache is invisible to the OS, as the caching is managed in hardware (where it can be tested with very low-level commands in a BIOS or EFI). I wouldn't expect to see a program able to monitor something invisible to the OS itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have proven my above comment incorrect. With [perf](http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-easiest-way-to-profile-my-application-to-see-the-CPU-cache-L1-L2-hit-miss-ratio-on-Linux), you can view system cache information much the same way `ps` will let you monitor cache hits/misses, which is just as good as anything else, as the cache is fully loaded as soon as enough data/instructions pass through it to fill it. Be aware that `linux-tools` (the package installed by `apt` for you to user `perf`) is kernel-specific. for instance when I went to install, I originally ran `sudo apt-get install linux-tools-common`, which then told me to install the correct version for my system (it even knew which kernel I was using!)

The link above suggests the command:

`perf stat -e L1-dcache-loads -e L1-dcache-load-misses echo test test`

Which didn't work on my system, likely due to the ancient 32-bit Intel Core Duo sitting in here (got a not supported return value). Newer systems I would expect to work more willingly, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks, pretty cool. It does work on my system. I do wish there was a gui. E.g, look at the tool he is using here: https://youtu.be/L7zSU9HI-6I?t=1h38m16s . Is there a Linux / Ubuntu equivalent to that GUI?

Comment: Seems like this is the tool he is using in the  video: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMClock